# What is $f'(\frac{1}{f(x)})$ in Leibniz's notation where $y=f(x)$ and $f(x)$ is differentiated with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find differentiable function whose reciprocal equals its inverse $f^{-1}(x)=[f(x)]^{-1}$. I read that there is no such function, but I still wanted to try. If the equality is true, then $f(f^{-1}(x))=f(\frac{1}{f(x)})=x$

I differentiated $f(\frac{1}{f(x)})=x$ with respect to $x$ and ended up with

$f'(\frac{1}{f(x)})*-\frac{1}{[f(x)]^{2}}*f'(x)=1$

Then attempted to rewrite the equation in Leibnizian notation so that I can use separation of variables to solve for $f(x)$

$f'(\frac{1}{f(x)})*-\frac{1}{y^2} *\frac{dy}{dx}=1$

$f'(\frac{1}{f(x)}) *\frac{dy}{dx}=-y^2$

I wrote $\frac{d(\frac{1}{y})}{dx}$ instead of $f'(\frac{1}{f(x)})$ first which is obviously wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please give, word for word and symbol for symbol, the actual question you started with. Please edit the post to include that. The differential equation you put in the comments below makes little sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If *it is given* that $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ *with respect to* $x$, then $f' \left( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)$ denotes the derivative of $f(x)$ evaluated (i.e. "plug in for $x$") at $x = \frac{1}{f(x)}$.

In Leibniz's notation that would be $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) \Big|_{x=\frac{1}{f(x)}}$. $\frac{d}{dx}$ differentiates $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. The pipe and the subscript $x = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ evaluates the derivative of $f(x)$ at that particular value. For instance, if $f(x) = x^2$, then $f'(x) = 2x$, implying that $\frac{df}{dx} \Big|_{x=\frac{1}{f(x)}} = f'(x) = 2\left( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right) = \frac{2}{f(x)}$.

Another possible case is that $f' \left( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)$ denotes the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ given that $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is the *parameter* of the function $f'$ instead of an *argument* (e.g. in a function $f(x)$ where $x$ is the parameter, examples of arguments would be 2, 7, $\pi$, etc.). In this case, we would notate the derivative as $\frac{df}{d \left( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)}$, where $\frac{df}{d \left( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)}$ denotes the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would this be the same as $\frac{dy}{d(\frac{1}{y})}=\frac{1}{(\frac{d(\frac{1}{y})}{dy})}=\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{y^2}}=-y^2$ since $x=\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: No, with $\frac{dy}{d\left( \frac{1}{y} \right)}$ you are differentiating $y$ with respect to $\frac{1}{y}$, but we are trying to differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$, denoted by $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and then *plug in* $\frac{1}{y}$ for $x$ of the differentiated function (e.g. the derivative of $x^2$ evaluated at 2 is 4 b/c the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$, and $2(2) = 4$); hence, "evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{y}$". This is notated with the big pipe and the subscript.

Comment: I'm attempting to solve $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2f'(\frac{1}{f(x)})=-xy^2$ by using seperation of variables, but I'm stuck at rewriting $f'(\frac{1}{f(x)})$ in Leibnizian notation. Is there any other way at rewriting this expression?

Comment: After looking at it I'm assuming that $f' \left( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)$ is indeed being differentiated with respect to $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

Solution: $\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 f'(\frac{1}{f(x)}) = -xy^2$.

$\frac{dx^2}{dy^2} \frac{dy}{d \left( \frac{1}{y} \right)} = -xy^2$.

$\frac{dx^2}{dy^2} \frac{dy}{\frac{-1}{y^2}dy \right)} = -xy^2$.

$-dy^2 = -xdx^2$.

Comment: @Post-Logic the previous differential equation I typed in the comments is wrong. I edited the question to include what I'm looking for.